# fwrite sometimes prints extra data in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I used c++ function "fwrite" to print an array of 128 float elements for 1920 iterations in VS2012 and in some iterations 516 bytes of data would be added to the BINARY FILE instead of 512 bytes, so I have to used the following technique to fix this problem.

```
image2.convertTo(image4, CV_32F);
image3 = fourier(image2, 50000.0);
image4 = line(image3);
if ((ftell(lineResult) - 4) % 128 != 0)
{
    fseek(lineResult, -((ftell(lineResult) - 4) & 511), SEEK_CUR);
}
fwrite(
    image4.data,
    //The 2nd param is always 512
    sizeof(float) * image4.rows * image4.cols,
    1,
    lineResult
);

fflush(lineResult);
```

Comment: You can try using `fflush()` after each iteration to get consistent results. It's up to the standard library to decide when to actually flush the write buffers to disk.

Comment: @egur I've used fflush every time after fwrite and it did't help